# Discord.py How can I send a PM to the mentioned user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I've made this **Ban** command but I want to code it to send a DM whenever I ban someone. I tried different types of codes but none of them worked. I'm pretty sure that it's just a word that I have to change but still could you have a look?

The code(Also it is inside a **Cog**):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Ban(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
    async def ban(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
        await member.ban(reason = reason)
        ban = discord.Embed(title='Ban Hammer Has Spoken! :boom:', description=f'**Moderator:** {ctx.author}\n **User Banned:** {member}\n **Reason:** {reason} ', color=0xbd2929)
        ban.set_author(name="Moderating Action", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=ban)
        dmban = discord.Embed(title=f'Ban Information From {ctx.guild}', discription=f'**Moderator:** Unknown\n **User Banned:** {member}\n **Reason:** {reason}', color=0xbd2929)
        await ctx.user.send(embed=dmban)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Ban(client))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The banned user is the `member` arg, simply do

```py
await member.send(...)
```